# Match words with hyphens and apostrophes

Tags: regex

I have the following regex for matching words:

```
\w+(?:'|\-\w+)?
```

For the following string:

```
' 's yea' don't -yeah no- ice-cream '
```

it gives the following matches:

`s` `yea'` `don't` `yeah` `no` `ice-cream`

However, I would like the following matches:

`'s` `yea'` `don't` `yeah` `no` `ice-cream`

Since a word can start or end with an apostrophe but not with a hyphen. Note the a ' on its own should not be matched.

Comment: _Since a word can start or end with a hyphen but not with an apostrophe._ contradicts your matches. `'s` and `yea'` are starting and ending with apostrophe.

Comment: @noob Correct, I've fixed this now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `\w+(?:'|\-\w+)?` starts matching with a word character `\w`, thus all "words" starting with `'` are not matched as per the requirements.

In general, you can **match words with and without hyphens** with

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

**In the current scenario**, you may include the `\w` and `'` into a character class and use

```
'?\w[\w']*(?:-\w+)*'?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN7hV8/2)

If a "word" can only have 1 hyphen, replace `*` at the end with the `?` quantifier.

Breakdown:

- `'?` - optional apostrophe
- `\w` - a word character
- `[\w']*` - 0+ word character or an apostrophe
- `(?:-\w+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\w+` -  1+ word character
- `'?` - optional apostrophe

Comment: This will match a ' on its own. I don't wish to match this.

Comment: I updated with another pattern, but perhaps, you can also try [`(?:\B'\b)?\w+(?:[-']\w+)*(?:\b'\B)?`](https://regex101.com/r/rN7hV8/3)